# Add random words at runtime inside jtextArea without using keyboard

Tags: java, random, jtextarea

As title said, i want to add at runtime words inside jtextArea, i simply wrote this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea tarea;

    public Test() {
        tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    }

    private void init() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        insertRandomLetterInsideJtextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tarea);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void insertRandomLetterInsideJtextArea() {
        while (true) {
            tarea.setText("foo\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().init();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but it don't work. The `while(true)` doesn't permit to show anything.
Someone can explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Timer do achieve this. 
try this :

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea tarea;

    public Test() {
        tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    }

    private void init() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tarea);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
        insertRandomLetterInsideJtextArea();
    }

    private void insertRandomLetterInsideJtextArea() {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            String content = "";
            @Override
            public void run() {
                content += "foo\n"; // here generate your random String
                tarea.setText(content);
            }
        }, 100, 1000); // firt is time before start, second is duration before repeat task, both in ms

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().init();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't permit to show anything, because the thread that is supposed to init everthing just loops forever in the while loop, so it can't do any further initializotion.

You need to start a thread in `insertRandomLetterInsideJtextArea`, like this:

```
private void insertRandomLetterInsideJtextArea() {
        new Thread() {
            Random r = new Random();
            public void run() {
              while (true) {
                try {
                  sleep(1000); // to not kill your app wait a little bit before adding next letter.
                  char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                  tarea.setText(tarea.getText() + c);             
                } catch (Exception e) {}
              }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```